# Anonymous contact form iOS app

Tags: ios

I currently work at a school and have an idea to create an app that allows students to contact a grown up (for example, the principle) anonymously through an app. The app would quite simply consist of a contact form. I am trying to find out the best, and easiest way to achieve this without setting up servers with a separate API. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to achieve it? Is there any way to set up an e-mail form with a pre set recipient and a built in sender-account? Please guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to implement an SMTP client. You can use open source code like [skpsmtpmessage](https://github.com/jetseven/skpsmtpmessage)

It's likely that their example app could be your solution.

Your biggest problem will be the deployment. You definitely need to pay an $99/y developer account and add all the students device ID's to your account (with a maximum of 100 devices/y) or register all of them as beta tester (I don't know the limitations).

Probably this isn't doable so easily, as it seems you don't have iOS developing experience so far. Maybe you can find something on the app store that works with self hosted databases. But you definitely need to host some kind of webApp/API.

Comment: Thank you! I have little experience in coding, probably sufficient to set it up, but the easiest way seems to go with the mobile-friendly website.

Comment: But does not meet your requirement of not needing an extra server / hosting environment either ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give [Appygram](http://appygram.com) a try to handle the back-end if you are able to set up the contact form itself.  While it's a separate hosted API, at least you don't have to build/manage it.

Appygram is a free web service that would allow you to configure all the details such as which adults could be contacted, their point(s) of contact (i.e. email address), and it would process and send all the submissions for you.  All your app needs to do is [send a form post request](http://www.appygram.com/docs#sending_an_appygram).

A nice thing about having this information outside of the iOS app itself is that you can change the contact details on the fly without requiring an update to the iOS app itself.  Whether you use Appygram (which, since I contribute to it, I am slightly biased toward!) or something similar, I would say that since this is for students, I would recommend a solution that would allow you to update your configuration without requiring app updates.

Finally, I'd second what Julian said.  The challenge here could be with deployment.  One possible alternative would be to make this a mobile-friendly web page accessible only via student login or on the school network (or both).  Would probably be easier development-wise and wouldn't require installs nor the hurdles that Julian described with device registration, etc.  And, Appygram would still work with this setup as well.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I am leaning towards the last alternative, using a mobile-friendly web page. Seems like it is the easiest way to go.